# Measuring array contiguity

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have records of data, where each record is a various-length array of integers in **strictly increasing order**. Here are some examples:

```
record_1 : 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10
record_2 : 5,30,31,32,33,34,35,36
record_3 : 10,11,12,19,20
```

I want to measure (or give score) of contiguity on each array, i.e. how "close" every adjacent elements of the array. Currently I'm using sum of difference of each adjacent array element (pseudo-code):

```
for i=2 to length(A) do
    sum_diff += A[i] - A[i-1]
end
score = (length(A) - 1) / sum_diff
```

So for a perfectly-continuous array (example: `1,2,3,4,5`) the score will be 1 (highest score).

But problem arises for a data that is contiguous but contains a "jump", for example `record_2` above, there is a "jump" from `5` to `30`.

For above data example, the scores using my algorithm are:

```
record_1 : 0.89
record_2 : 0.23
record_3 : 0.4
```

It gives score to `record_2` lower than `record_3`, but we can **intuitively** see that `record_2` should has higher score than `record_3` because `record_2` is contiguous except the jump from `5` to `30`.

So, does anyone have an idea on how should I modify my algorithm to give better contiguity measurement? Thanks before.

Comment: Assuming you mean `sum_diff += A[i] - A[i-1]`, and that your monotonicity guarantee holds, note that your given algorithm is equivalent to `score = (length(A) - 1) / (A[length(A)-1] - A[0])`, i.e. that the values in the middle of the series are completely irrelevant to the overall score.

Comment: I can't intuitively see that *record_2* should have a higher score. One break of sequence in 8 sounds better than one in 5.

Comment: @Weeble : sorry for the mistake, edited my question, thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadAbrar seeing how are you going to use this value might help.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to give a terribly useful answer without a better idea of what you intend to use this score for. Is number of discontinuities more important than size? Does it matter whether discontinuities are clumped together or should it make no difference?

Comment: @JonasElfström : I mean the "overall contiguity", so a single "long jump" shouldn't affect the score so much.

Comment: Ok, I'm using this score to rank a search result. I'm implementing an approximate substring matching using n-grams, and those arrays are the position of n-grams occurences on the searched strings. So a contiguous position should rate better than long non-contiguous one (so contiguity is more important than the length). I'm considering @Weeble's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're considering a gap of 2 to be as bad as a gap of 10, then average the "is different by one" function:

```
differenceMeasures[i] = A[i+1] - A[i] == 1 ? 1 : 0
return average of differenceMeasures
// Note that the average will be sum(differenceMeasures)/(n-1) since there's
// one less difference than there is number of array entries in 'A'.
```

If you want to take gap sizes into account, I recommend using a monotonically decreasing function bounded at zero like reciprocation:

```
differenceMeasures[i] = 1 / A[i+1] - A[i]
return average of differenceMeasures
// When the difference is 1, differenceMeasures gets 1.
// When 2, differenceMeasures gets 1/2. Etc...
```

In both of these functions `1` is the optimal score at `0` is the least optimal. If you don't like that, it's easy enough to `return 1 - average of differenceMeasures`.

Comment: I do consider gap sizes. Using reciprocation to "smoothen" the big gaps should be a good idea.